# AddToShipoutPictureFG on speicifc page

Tags: positioning

I'm using [Werner's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24663/43770) to the specified floating-text-box problem, but there is no way to specify which page the result goes on. I was wondering if there's a way to tell `AddToShipoutPictureFG` which page to go onto.

So, like the interface, instead of being

```
\placetextbox{<horizontal pos>}{<vertical pos>}{<stuff>}
```

would be

```
\placetextbox{page}{<horizontal pos>}{<vertical pos>}{<stuff>}
```

Comment: My answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194378/big-watermark-for-tiled-pages/222344#222344 shows how to check the page number and decide what content to place at shipout using an every-page-hook with page test.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hi, that worked! I just used `\AddToShipoutPictureFG` (no star) and then added an `\ifthenelse{\equals{#1}{\thepage}}{asdf}{}`. If you want to mark this question as a duplicate of that one or answer it, go ahead